# HTML table not formatting properly in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having problems getting a table to format correctly in one of my views for rails. The view shows the items for an order.

Here is the view:

```
<h3>Order for <%= @demand.customer.name %></h3>
<h4>Ordered for: <%= @demand.date %></h4>
<h4>Add Items</h4>

<%= render 'demands/item_form' %>

<table class="customer-table">
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th style="padding-left: 30px;">Sub Total</th>
</tr>

<% @demand.items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.price %></td>
     <% item.demand_items.each do |quantity| %>
        <td><%= quantity.quantity %></td>
        <td class="sub-total" style="padding-left: 30px;">
        <%= (item.price) * (quantity.quantity) %></td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

</tr> 

</table>
```

Here is a few screenshots of the issue. Everything in the red box and to the right of it shouldn't be there : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCDzK.png

I'm still pretty new to developing so this is probably something simple.

Comment: How many objects are in the `item.demand_items` collection? It looks like you're getting way more objects than expected.

Comment: @Michael you have not used the close tags in the right place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped this from happening by ending the second `each` loop.

Here is the fixed code

```
<% @demand.items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.price %></td>
     <% item.demand_items.each do |quantity| %>
        <td><%= quantity.quantity %></td>
        <td class="sub-total" style="padding-left: 30px;">
        <%= subtotal(item.price, quantity.quantity) %></td>
      <% break %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

The second pair of `tr` is not correct. Put the last `tr` tag inside loop, like this

```
    </tr> 
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Good catch, but `</tr>` closing tags are **optional**. Each iteration of `<tr>` should insert a new row. He is going sideways indicating one too many `<td>`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. You are right I have one two many TDs. Everything in that red box and to the right of it should not be there. I'll try move the tr and see if that fixes it, but I don't think I tried that before and it didn't work.